# How can my custom TOS component add columns to output based on input schema/metadata?

Tags: java, custom-component, etl, talend

I'm using Talend Open Studio for Data Integration and I would like to create a custom component that will output the input data as well as some extra columns that will be derived from the input columns.  As a proof of concept, in the following code I'm trying to create a duplicate column for every column, but the real example will have more complicated logic.  Here's what I tried in the "begin" portion of my .javajet file for the component:

```
<%@ jet
    imports="
        org.talend.core.model.process.INode
        org.talend.core.model.process.ElementParameterParser
        org.talend.core.model.metadata.IMetadataTable
        org.talend.core.model.metadata.IMetadataColumn
        org.talend.core.model.process.IConnection
        org.talend.core.model.process.IConnectionCategory
        org.talend.designer.codegen.config.CodeGeneratorArgument
        org.talend.core.model.metadata.types.JavaTypesManager
        org.talend.core.model.metadata.types.JavaType
        java.util.List
        java.util.Map       
    "
%>
<%
    CodeGeneratorArgument codeGenArgument = (CodeGeneratorArgument) argument;
    INode node = (INode)codeGenArgument.getArgument();
    String cid = node.getUniqueName();   

    IConnection conn = node.getOutgoingConnections().get(0);
    IMetadataTable outputMetadataTable = conn.getMetadataTable();

    List<IMetadataTable> metadatas = node.getMetadataList();
    IMetadataTable metadata = metadatas.get(0);

    List<IMetadataColumn> columnsToAdd = new java.util.ArrayList<IMetadataColumn>();
    for(IMetadataColumn col : outputMetadataTable.getListColumns()){
      IMetadataColumn cloned = col.clone();
      cloned.setLabel("Clone_of_" + cloned.getLabel());
      columnsToAdd.add(cloned);
    }

    List<IMetadataColumn> cols = new java.util.ArrayList<IMetadataColumn>(outputMetadataTable.getListColumns());
    cols.addAll(columnsToAdd);
    outputMetadataTable.setListColumns(cols);

%>
```

This seems to almost work, but not quite.  If I add my component as part of a flow with a single input and single output, the output does indeed show the desired extra columns.  However, the generated Java code nevertheless has compile errors.  It looks like the "struct" for the output to my component does not have fields to represent the additional columns.  That is, if row1 is the input and row2 is the output, the row2Struct class does not have the extra fields that are represented by the change to the metadata.  So even though the UI will show me that those columns exist in the output, it seems I am not able to actually put any values into those columns.

Since I am able to change what columns are in the metadata, there must be a way for me to let this be reflected in the structs for the row, right?  Is there some sort of "update" method or something that I am missing?

Answer (score -1):

In this case, row2Struct constructor need to called in the java code generated by your _main.javajet like this :

```
<%
String outConnName = conn.getName();
%>
<%=outConnName %> = new <%=outConnName %>Struct();
```

Then if you want to copy some input data in your output data flow, you can generate the following java code :

```
<%
for ( IMetadataColumn outColumn : outColumns) {
%>
<%=outConnName%>.<%=outColumn.getLabel()%> = <%=inConnName%>.<%=outColumn.getLabel()%>;
<%
}
%>
```

Comment: I can access the row2Struct, but the problem is that it only has the original fields, not the new fields that I added in my being.javajet.

Comment: To be a little more clear why this does not work, the generated Java code has compile errors when referencing row2.Clone_of_Column1, etc.  The row2Struct does not have a field for the clone columns, and I get the message "Clone_of_Column1 cannot be resolved or is not a field."

Comment: Ok, I understand now. It is not supported to modify your component metadata in javajet. Javajet code is only used for java code generation (NOT component parameters control)